# Web Service can not connect to mySql hosted by Amazon Web Services

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, web-services

I have a web service that I developed using Visual Studio 2015.  When I test the web service from within VS2015 via WCF Test Client, I am able to select the web service method I want to call and Invoke it.  The web service then connects to a mySql database that is hosted by Amazon Web Services. The web service then returns the data is read from my database and I can see the data in the WCF.  When I launch the WCF Test Client from a command prompt and enter the service manually, select the service method I want to call and click on Invoke, the web service is executed but is unable to connect to the mySql database.  The error message that I get back is Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Why would the web service be able to connect to the mySql database when called from the WCF within VS2015 but can not access the mySQL database when called from the WCF launched from the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow amazon manual? I believe there also was a step involved to whitelist the connecting IP

Comment: I did not know there was a manual.  Where can I find that?  But wouldn't the ip address be the same?  In both instances, I am launching WCF from my laptop.  Once from within VS2015 and once from the command prompt.  But both are on my laptop so both should have the same ip address.  right?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/?nc2=h_ql_d&awsm=ql-5

Comment: And when I created the database, I selected to make the database public so it should be accessible.  And as I stated, I get data back from it when I execute WCF from within VS2015.  Just not when I execute WCF from a command prompt.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just created a web api which I tested locally and it connects to the mySql database and inserts data and retrieves data. When I publish the api to my AWS account, it can not access the mySql database.  AWS must have some restriction even though when I created my database I selected it to be public.  I will have to contact AWS to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be security related.  I had to put the public IP address of my WebAPI in a security rule of the database, similar to what I had to do in order to allow my local machine to access the mySql database.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a security issue.If it is securely related.This is solution:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Im not sure if this would work.  The error message I am getting back (Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts) appears to indicate that the WebAPI can not connect to the database, not that they can't be logged into.

Comment: Did you check whether the server has remote access turned on?

Comment: If you can reach you database at remote.You should define also localhost user grant for mysql.

Comment: I had to add the IP address of the EC2 instance that m WebAPI is hosted on into a security rule for the database.  I'm able to call my API now.  Thanks.